R function output can't find name of the object
I have 4 data objects (AR1, AR2, AR3, and AR4) which contain the regression output information (each obtained after running dynlm function which is part of dynlm package). I tried to run the following function which should return test statistics obtained by LjungBox function (part of the portes package) for each of these models (where I use the number of observations of the model and the length of the coefficients variable):
ljungbox <- function(x) {
qx <- floor(0.7 * nobs(ARx)^(1/3)) 
dfx <- qx - length(ARx$coefficients)
LjungBox(ARx$residuals, lags = 1:qx, fitdf = dfx)
}

However, when trying to get the output of the function for the first model, it results in a following error:
> print(ljungbox(1))
Error in nobs(ARx) : object 'ARx' not found

What could be the problem and how can I solve it?
Thanks in advance!

Object names aren't parsed. If I have a data set named my_data, and I set a <- 1, it doesn't start looking for my_d1t1. And when you have an object named AR1, if you try to use ARx it doesn't matter if you set x <- 1 or x <- "hello", ARx is still ARx, not AR1 or ARhello.

The best way to go is probably to put your models in a list, see my answer at How to make a list of data frames. It's best to do this up-front, but you can still do it now with something like AR_list = mget(paste0("AR", 1:4)). Then you can define your function to take a model object as input, ljungbox <- function(x) { qx <- floor(0.7 * nobs(x)^(1/3));  dfx <- qx - length(x$coefficients); LjungBox(x$residuals, lags = 1:qx, fitdf = dfx) }...

and then if you want to run it on one you can do ljungbox(AR_list[[1]]) or run it on all of them with lapply(AR_list, ljungbox)
